# Best Way to reuse Modal in angular 2

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

In my project, i use different modals for Edit, Add. I want to reuse the Modal So that I don't need to rewrite it all the time. How do I do that? What would be the best way to reuse a model. Can anyone give me an example? I checked other questions but I am not able to understand them properly. As I am new to angular. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this would be to create a modal component. 
This component should then have a template which is the modal code only, allowing content to be passed to each instance of the component.

It might be good to follow some tutorials on https://angular.io/ if you are new to angular, as some concepts will be confusing. Also https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction has more information on how to do this

your component could have a definition as:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.html'
 })
```

then in dialog.html:

```
<div #container>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

`#container` represents your dialog code, and within your dialog is the directive `<ng-content>` telling angular to place whatever content you use within an instance of the component there. You would then use the dialog as follows:

```
<my-dialog>
  <p>this content will appear in the dialog</p>
</my-dialog>
```

Comment: Can you refer me to a working example? I tried it but it's not working perfectly. I am still confused a bit. How do I keep the data target for the modal?